# Why can't I create a ThreadPool in cx_Freeze?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, python-multiprocessing, cx-freeze

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Jun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run

    module.run()

  File "C:\Users\Jun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run

    exec(code, m.__dict__)

  File "D:/ruanjian/new/Ui-Design/hand_up_625.py", line 25, in <module>

    from keras.models import load_model

  File "C:\Users\Jun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

    from . import utils

  File "C:\Users\Jun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

    from . import data_utils

  File "C:\Users\Jun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 19, in <module>

    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

ImportError: No module named 'multiprocessing.pool'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `'multiprocessing'` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe_options` in the `setup.py` script:

```py
build_exe_options = {"packages": ['multiprocessing']}

# ...

setup(  name = ...,  # complete!
        ...
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable(...)])
```

See the cx_Freeze [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#distutils-setup-script) for further details.

Please also notice that you will have to call `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` for your frozen script to keep working with multiprocessing. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support):

> Add support for when a program which uses multiprocessing has been frozen to produce a Windows executable. (Has been tested with **py2exe**, **PyInstaller** and **cx_Freeze**.)
>
> One needs to call this function straight after the `if __name__ == '__main__'` line of the main module. For example:
>
> ```py
> from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
>
> def f():
>     print('hello world!')
>
> if __name__ == '__main__':
>     freeze_support()
>     Process(target=f).start()
> ```
>
> If the `freeze_support()` line is omitted then trying to run the frozen executable will raise RuntimeError.
>
> Calling `freeze_support()` has no effect when invoked on any operating system other than Windows. In addition, if the module is being run normally by the Python interpreter on Windows (the program has not been frozen), then `freeze_support()` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks like you're missing the [multiprocessing library](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing/), which you can get with pip.

Second, [Python 3.5's multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) doesn't include ThreadPool. If you want a process pool, you're looking for:

```
 class multiprocessing.pool.Pool([processes[, initializer[, initargs[, maxtasksperchild[, context]]]]])
```

Comment: Now the question is about the import error, No module named 'multiprocessing.pool'. The cx_Freeze can't find the module:'multiprocessing.pool', i need to make an executable (.exe). The code can run exactly, but it got a import error when i use cx_Freeze to make an executable, but i did find the pool.py in multiprocessing

Comment: It sounds like cx_freeze isn't seeing that library -- does [the cx_freeze documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html) solution regarding includes / packages help?